# The program doesn't callback after dialogbox() is called

Tags: c++, windows, bass

This is a sample program I downloaded from un4seen.com, bass audio library sample. However, when I try to build it no window is shown although it successfully generates the executable file and runs. I tried to add few breakpoints and figured that the program ends immediatly after it called Dialogbox() and didn't do callback. Can anyone tell me what the problem is?

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <commctrl.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include "bass.h"
#pragma comment( lib, "comctl32.lib " ) 

HWND win = NULL;

#define MESS(id,m,w,l) SendDlgItemMessage(win,id,m,(WPARAM)(w),(LPARAM)(l))

HRECORD rchan;  // recording channel
HSTREAM chan;   // playback stream
HFX fx[4] = { 0 };  // FX handles
int chunk;      // recording chunk size
int input;      // current input source
int latency = 0;    // current latency

#define SAMPLERATE 44100
#define ADJUSTRATE // adjust the output rate (in case input and output devices are going at slightly different speeds)

DWORD rate;     // current output rate
DWORD prebuf;   // prebuffering amount
#ifdef ADJUSTRATE
DWORD targbuf;  // target buffer level
DWORD prevbuf;  // previous buffer level/threshold
#endif

void Error(const char *es)
{
    char mes[200];
    sprintf(mes, "%s\n(error code: %d)", es, BASS_ErrorGetCode());
    MessageBox(win, mes, 0, 0);
}

BOOL CALLBACK RecordingCallback(HRECORD handle, const void *buffer, DWORD length, void *user)
{
    DWORD bl;
    BASS_StreamPutData(chan, buffer, length); // feed recorded data to output stream
    bl = BASS_ChannelGetData(chan, NULL, BASS_DATA_AVAILABLE); // get output buffer level
    if (prebuf) { // prebuffering
        if (bl >= prebuf + length) { // gone 1 block past the prebuffering target
#ifdef ADJUSTRATE
            targbuf = bl; // target the current level
            prevbuf = 0;
#endif
            prebuf = 0; // finished prebuffering
            BASS_ChannelPlay(chan, FALSE); // start the output
        }
    }
    else { // playing
#ifdef ADJUSTRATE
        if (bl<targbuf) { // buffer level is below target, slow down...
            rate--;
            BASS_ChannelSetAttribute(chan, BASS_ATTRIB_FREQ, rate);
            prevbuf = 0;
        }
        else if (bl>targbuf && bl >= prevbuf) { // buffer level is high and not falling, speed up...
            rate++;
            BASS_ChannelSetAttribute(chan, BASS_ATTRIB_FREQ, rate);
            prevbuf = bl;
        }
#endif
    }
    return TRUE; // continue recording
}

BOOL Initialize()
{
    BASS_INFO bi;

    BASS_SetConfig(BASS_CONFIG_VISTA_TRUEPOS, 0); // allows lower latency on Vista and newer

                                                  // initialize default output device (and measure latency)
    if (!BASS_Init(-1, SAMPLERATE, BASS_DEVICE_LATENCY, win, NULL)) {
        Error("Can't initialize output");
        return FALSE;
    }

    BASS_GetInfo(&bi);
    if (bi.dsver<8) { // no DX8, so disable effect buttons
        EnableWindow(GetDlgItem(win, 20), FALSE);
        EnableWindow(GetDlgItem(win, 21), FALSE);
        EnableWindow(GetDlgItem(win, 22), FALSE);
        EnableWindow(GetDlgItem(win, 23), FALSE);
    }

    // create a stream to play the recording
    chan = BASS_StreamCreate(SAMPLERATE, 2, 0, STREAMPROC_PUSH, 0);

    rate = SAMPLERATE;
    prebuf = BASS_ChannelSeconds2Bytes(chan, bi.minbuf / 1000.f); // prebuffer at least "minbuf" worth of data

                                                                  // start recording with 10ms period
    if (!BASS_RecordInit(-1) || !(rchan = BASS_RecordStart(SAMPLERATE, 2, MAKELONG(0, 10), RecordingCallback, 0))) {
        BASS_RecordFree();
        BASS_Free();
        Error("Can't initialize recording");
        return FALSE;
    }

    { // get list of inputs
        int c;
        const char *i;
        for (c = 0; i = BASS_RecordGetInputName(c); c++) {
            float level;
            MESS(10, CB_ADDSTRING, 0, i);
            if (!(BASS_RecordGetInput(c, &level)&BASS_INPUT_OFF)) { // this 1 is currently "on"
                input = c;
                MESS(10, CB_SETCURSEL, input, 0);
                MESS(11, TBM_SETPOS, TRUE, level * 100); // set level slider
            }
        }
    }

    return TRUE;
}

INT_PTR CALLBACK dialogproc(HWND h, UINT m, WPARAM w, LPARAM l)
{
    switch (m) {
    case WM_TIMER:
    { // display current latency (input+output buffer level)
        char buf[20];
        latency = (latency * 3 + BASS_ChannelGetData(chan, NULL, BASS_DATA_AVAILABLE)
            + BASS_ChannelGetData(rchan, NULL, BASS_DATA_AVAILABLE)) / 4;
        sprintf(buf, "%d", (int)(BASS_ChannelBytes2Seconds(chan, latency) * 1000));
        MESS(15, WM_SETTEXT, 0, buf);
    }
    break;

    case WM_COMMAND:
        switch (LOWORD(w)) {
        case IDCANCEL:
            DestroyWindow(h);
            break;
        case 10:
            if (HIWORD(w) == CBN_SELCHANGE) { // input selection changed
                int i;
                float level;
                input = MESS(10, CB_GETCURSEL, 0, 0); // get the selection
                for (i = 0; BASS_RecordSetInput(i, BASS_INPUT_OFF, -1); i++); // 1st disable all inputs, then...
                BASS_RecordSetInput(input, BASS_INPUT_ON, -1); // enable the selected input
                BASS_RecordGetInput(input, &level); // get the level
                MESS(11, TBM_SETPOS, TRUE, level * 100);
            }
            break;
        case 20: // toggle chorus
            if (fx[0]) {
                BASS_ChannelRemoveFX(chan, fx[0]);
                fx[0] = 0;
            }
            else
                fx[0] = BASS_ChannelSetFX(chan, BASS_FX_DX8_CHORUS, 0);
            break;
        case 21: // toggle gargle
            if (fx[1]) {
                BASS_ChannelRemoveFX(chan, fx[1]);
                fx[1] = 0;
            }
            else
                fx[1] = BASS_ChannelSetFX(chan, BASS_FX_DX8_GARGLE, 0);
            break;
        case 22: // toggle reverb
            if (fx[2]) {
                BASS_ChannelRemoveFX(chan, fx[2]);
                fx[2] = 0;
            }
            else
                fx[2] = BASS_ChannelSetFX(chan, BASS_FX_DX8_REVERB, 0);
            break;
        case 23: // toggle flanger
            if (fx[3]) {
                BASS_ChannelRemoveFX(chan, fx[3]);
                fx[3] = 0;
            }
            else
                fx[3] = BASS_ChannelSetFX(chan, BASS_FX_DX8_FLANGER, 0);
            break;
        }
        break;

    case WM_HSCROLL:
        if (l) { // set input source level
            float level = SendMessage((HWND)l, TBM_GETPOS, 0, 0) / 100.f;
            if (!BASS_RecordSetInput(input, 0, level)) // failed to set input level
                BASS_RecordSetInput(-1, 0, level); // try master level instead
        }
        break;

    case WM_INITDIALOG:
        win = h;
        MESS(11, TBM_SETRANGE, FALSE, MAKELONG(0, 100)); // initialize input level slider
        MessageBox(win,
            "Do not set the input to 'WAVE' / 'What you hear' (etc...) with\n"
            "the level set high, as that is likely to result in nasty feedback.\n",
            "Feedback warning", MB_ICONWARNING);
        if (!Initialize()) {
            DestroyWindow(win);
            break;
        }
        SetTimer(h, 1, 250, NULL);
        return 1;

    case WM_DESTROY:
        KillTimer(h, 1);
        // release it all
        BASS_RecordFree();
        BASS_Free();
        break;
    }
    return 0;
}

int PASCAL WinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance, LPSTR lpCmdLine, int nCmdShow)
{
    // check the correct BASS was loaded
    if (HIWORD(BASS_GetVersion()) != BASSVERSION) {
        MessageBox(0, "An incorrect version of BASS.DLL was loaded", 0, MB_ICONERROR);
        return 0;
    }

    { // enable trackbar support (for the level control)
        INITCOMMONCONTROLSEX cc = { sizeof(cc),ICC_BAR_CLASSES };
        InitCommonControlsEx(&cc);
    }

    DialogBox(hInstance, (char*)1000, 0, &dialogproc);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This line:

```
DialogBox(hInstance, (char*)1000, 0, &dialogproc);
```

is likely failing because the resource (1000) is missing.

The second parameter is resource ID - but to a resource that isn't linked in.  That is, your linked in .res (compiled from .rc file) should a have a dialog template defined with an ID of 1000. The dialog template defines the layout of the dialog, buttons, controls and positions of each.  Are you sure you aren't missing a `.rc` file that came with that sample `.cpp` file?  If you have that rc file, add it to your Visual Studio project.

What's odd is that resource IDs (and command IDs of dialog controls) are rarely hardcoded numbers in code. You typically have a `resource.h` file that that defines `#define IDD_DIALOG1 1000` or something similar. It's included by both the `resource.rc` file as well as the C/C++ code.

**Update** - I suspect you are trying to compile the `basstest` project that comes with the download of bass24.zip.  But you only compiled the .c file, and not the corresponding basstest.rc file.

Comment: thank you so much for the help. do you know how to compile rc file, i dont find any resources online

Comment: sorry i was ignorant, figured out after reading your reply again

Answer (score 0):

You should inspect all the values returned.

```
::INT_PTR const result(::DialogBox(hInstance, (char*)1000, 0, &dialogproc));
if(-1 == result)
{
    ::DWORD const last_error(::GetLastError());
    // check error code...
}
```

Also `(char*)1000` is rather suspicious, typically you include header with resource file definitions and use `MAKEINTRESOURCE(MY_DLG_ID)`.